# MacBook Air 2017 no longer sends any signal to monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

My MacBook Air 2017 isn't sending any signal to my Dell monitor, and it doesn't work on my TV either.

I am using a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter that I got online and it worked perfectly last week both on the monitor and the TV.

I updated the software, I restarted the MacBook and I took the power out of the monitor and still nothing is working.